# Gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, system

I'm sending an HTTP request to my web server and its task is to compile a file exploiting the system() function. I'm trying to compile this code:

```
system("gcc -o testFile testFile.c")
```

However, I receive this error:

```
error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I'm not that expert in both linux and C. Anybody can help to fix this issue?

I tried the solution available and it did not work

Comment: That sounds like a broken gcc install.

Comment: @Timmy Look up in the documentation for your linux distro on how to install and remove packages, then remove the existing gcc package(s), and install it again.

Comment: @Timmy: what is the 'solution available' that you tried and did not work?  Can you compile programs without going through the web server?  If you can compile from a terminal window but not from the web server, it is probably an environment issue — maybe the setting of `$PATH`, or maybe something else.  Normally though, if you can find `gcc` to run it, then it can find its backend tools; they are in a specified location.  If you can't compile form the terminal window (same or similar error), it is time to reinstall.

Comment: on the terminal window, the command works fine. When I send the request and want it to compile the same command it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I managed to solve this problem:

```
system("export  PATH=$PATH; gcc -o  testFile    testFile.c")
```